# How to read text file from File object in java

Tags: java, file

I have this code which load the File from class path
a=its text file and i want to read it to string 
what im using is :

```
 File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("sample.json").getFile());
```

i don't want to use:

```
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

how can i read this text file into String ?

**UPDATE** 
i found the solution , what do you think?

```
 ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("sample.json");
String txt = IOUtils.toString(is);
```

Comment: what relevance has `file.getAbsolutePath();` to do with your question?

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Comment: `Files.readAllLines();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: Load  the file..parse the JSON...in for loop you can convert it to string...

Comment: Duplicate? There is a couple of similar questions on SO already! What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8, you can use this for reading lines from a file:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readallLines(file.toPath());
```

Refer to the docs below:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--

**EDIT:**

For reading from a resource you got as an inputstream, you can use a combination of `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`:

```
String getText() throws IOException{
    StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.json");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res))) {
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            txt.append(sCurrentLine + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return txt.toString();
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to read the file object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file)) {
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```